# Add "Search My Activity" to the "Close as Duplicate" dialog

Tags: feature-request, search, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

When I'm the first person voting to close a question as a duplicate, I know it is because I have interacted with the question before myself.

Is it possible for the default search to be in the active users activity?

If I saw the questions I have asked / answered / starred / upvoted first, it would be better than a pure search.

Currently I need to fire up another window and search my activity there to paste my duplicate into the box.